# Items not being pushed to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to create an array from Google Maps JSON data, within a JQuery each function.

To that effect I have:

```
var markerlocations = new Array();

$(function() {

$(".markerloc").each(function( index ) {
    var addressval = $(this).val();

    var jsonLtdLng="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + addressval;

    $.getJSON(jsonLtdLng, function (data) {

        var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

        var latlng = "{lat: " + lat + ", lng: " + lng + "}";

        markerlocations.push(latlng);

        console.log(latlng);

    });//END JSON

  });//END EACH

    console.log(markerlocations);

});//END PAGE READY
```

`console.log(latlng);` produces the expected result, but this does not seem to be pushed to the `markerlocations` array - the console just shows it as empty.

Would anyone know what's going on here and be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: That is because ajax is executed asynchronously

Comment: ... and you should also push an object to the array, not a string: `markerlocations.push({ lat: lat, lng: lng });`